# In mssql Summing values in a cell with '$$' separated Integers, but data type is varchar

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sum

I have below table with Table data

```
ID  |Department | SaleMngrs(VARCHAR(200))  | 
---------------------------------------------
1   |Technics   | '1$$2$$3$$4'| 
2   |Development| '10$$21$$43'|
```

I want the result as given below

```
ID  |Department | SaleMngrs   | sum 
-------------------------------------
1   |Technics   | '1$$2$$3$$4'| 10
2   |Development| '10$$21$$43'| 74
```

Comment: does my answer helpful to you? 
if you have any doubt then ask.
i spent more than hour for that.

Comment: Chirag, is there any way to do this with out functions, in my case the length varies on each cell

Comment: which length you talking about?
can you give me an example?

Comment: 1,  1$$2$$3$$4,  1$$20,  10$$20$$30$$40  like this. some dosent have any $$ symbol.

Comment: don't worry, it will work for all, i made it dynamic.
try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL server then use **Solution number #1** or if you are using MySql then go for **solution number #2**

**Solution #1**

For SQL server it would be better to use Function to split the string and get the values from it, you need to Create the Below function

**Function SplitStrings**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitStrings
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(2)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

After Executing this function run this below query

```
SELECT ID, Department, SaleMngrs, 
       (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT,Item)) FROM dbo.SplitString(SaleMngrs, '$$')) AS Sum 
From Temp_Table
```

**solution #2**

```
SELECT ID, Department, SaleMngrs, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SaleMngrs,'$$',1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SaleMngrs,'$$0'),'$$',2),'$$',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SaleMngrs,'$$0'),'$$',3),'$$',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SaleMngrs,'$$0'),'$$',4),'$$',-1) +
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(SaleMngrs,'$$0'),'$$',5),'$$',-1) AS SUM 
From Temp_Table;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle URL, you can check here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de5066/1

Comment: 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name in microsoftsql server 2008

Comment: @rock i have done it for Mysql as you mentioned it in question tag

Comment: Thak you chirag, but what about SUBSTRING_INDEX function in mssql

Comment: @rock Let me try for SQL server 2008

Comment: @rock i have done it for sql server too, check the Solution #1

Comment: Chirag, is there any way with out using functions. In my case the length of the varchar string varies in its length.

Comment: @rock i didn't get it, can you please explain it properly?

Comment: Solution #2  works fine in mysql, Thank you chirag for your valuable time spent on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `data (VARCHAR to INTEGER)` and after that get your **sum**.

By the way could you explain it more? Because Your question is a little puzzling.

Comment: data type is varchar(200),  values will be '21$$31$$50' but  i want the sum of 21+31+50=102.  i want 102 as the answer

Comment: @sparrow7000 he knows it, he wants to know how to do it.